# Check if variable used to trigger popup

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Hello I'm working on a wordpress site and I currently have a popup set to display if an arrtibute in the shortcode is set to "popup="register")... I added another lightbox that I want to display if the attribute is set to "popup="apply")

My question is how to add another variable to the following function.. would I need an if statement? Im new to php, any advice is greatly appreciated.. Thanks!!!!

```
function oxy_shortcode_button_fancy($atts , $content = '' ) {
     // setup options
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'button_swatch'     => 'swatch-coral',
        'button_animation'  => '',
        'size'              => 'default',
        'xclass'            => '',
        'link'              => '',
        'label'             => 'My button',
        'icon'              => '',
        'link_open'         => '_self',
        'popup'             => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    $popup = ('register' == $popup) ? ' onclick="jQuery(\'#registerid, .overlayLogin\').show();"' : '';
    $animation = ( $button_animation != "") ? ' data-animation="'.$button_animation.'"' :"";
    return '<a'.$popup.' href="'. $link .'" class="btn '. $size.' btn-icon-right '. $xclass . ' '. $button_swatch .'" target="' . $link_open . '"> '. $label . '<span><i class="'.$icon.'" '.$animation.'></i></span></a>';



    }
```

What i'm looking to add is:

```
$popup = ('apply' == $popup) ? ' onclick="jQuery(\'#applyid, .overlayLogin\').show();"' : '';
```

Comment: You are right..Do the way u mentioned  there

Comment: @VaibhavBhanushali it does not work when added right below the first  $popup = ('register' == $popup)....

Comment: Did u use the if else statments to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this codes..Hope it helps you

```
  function oxy_shortcode_button_fancy($atts , $content = '' ) {
 // setup options
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'button_swatch'     => 'swatch-coral',
    'button_animation'  => '',
    'size'              => 'default',
    'xclass'            => '',
    'link'              => '',
    'label'             => 'My button',
    'icon'              => '',
    'link_open'         => '_self',
    'popup'             => ''
), $atts ) );


 if('register' == $popup) {
$popup = ('register' == $popup) ? ' onclick="jQuery(\'#registerid, .overlayLogin\').show();"' : '';
} else {
$popup = ('apply' == $popup) ? ' onclick="jQuery(\'#applyid, .overlayLogin\').show();"' : '';
}
$animation = ( $button_animation != "") ? ' data-animation="'.$button_animation.'"' :"";
return '<a'.$popup.' href="'. $link .'" class="btn '. $size.' btn-icon-right '. $xclass . ' '. $button_swatch .'" target="' . $link_open . '"> '. $label . '<span><i class="'.$icon.'" '.$animation.'></i></span></a>';



}
```